# How to get all cells in a particular column?

Tags: c#, excel, linq, openxml

I have a program that get data from cells then record those information in a separate application. Following is the code snippet for cell extraction.

```
TableStructure tableStructure = new tableStructure();
tableStructure.TableCols = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"};
tableStructure.StartRow = 1;
tableStructure.EndRow = 4001;
foreach (var colName in tableStructure.TableCols)
{
    for (var ci = tableStructure.StartRow; ci <= tableStructure.EndRow; ci++)
    {
        var addressName = colName + ci;
        Cell currentCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();//52000 times
        //some other scripts
    }
}
```

from this code I am able to get my desired output but there is a performance issue. For the above example it take around 9 minutes to get the cells only. if I comment the following line then It take only 50 seconds.
`Cell currentCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => c.CellReference == addressName).FirstOrDefault();`
I want to optimize my code like there is a LINQ through which I can get all the cells 
`Descendants<Row>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.RowIndex == rowIndex)`
 Now my question is that is there a way like above From which I can get all the cells of a particular column.

Comment: Is this c# to excel ? Show the code where you load your excel file.

Comment: thakns,@JamesDev I am using open xml for reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Cell> cells = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare(GetColumnName(c.CellReference.Value),
addressName, true) == 0).OrderBy(r => GetRowIndex(r.CellReference));

foreach (var cell in cells)
{

}
```

Comment: GetRowIndex(r.CellReference)) Where is this function? are you copy from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc822064.aspx this link?

Comment: if i m correct then i already tried that one and has same effect

Comment: You mean it is still slow ?